# Add more PR status check (Jenkins blue ocean, integrated with github)

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I was installing Jenkins (with blue ocean plugin) and successfully configure GitHub webhook, so that, every push to the repository will be checked whether the build process succeeds or not (like this attached image).

[image]

After installing there are 2 status checks that installed by default

- jenkins/branch: check if commit could be built successfully and report status back to GitHub
- jenkins/pr-merge: check if PR could be merged with the base branch (currently develop) and report status back to GitHub

I want to **add 1 more status check, like Jenkins/unit-test**. How could I do that from Jenkins side? And where are the 2 status checks mentioned above defined in Jenkins with blue ocean plugin?

The reason I want to add more status check is that I can configure this check as optional, so even unit test failed, I can still merge the pull request.
(Our project is still in very early development stages, then it is not necessary to require all unit test to pass to merge a PR at the moment.)

Comment: *"it is not necessary to require all unit tests to pass"* - I would strongly encourage you to rethink this. That's a slippery slope to never having all the tests passing, and the signal of failures you care about lost in the noise of failures you don't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much for your advice. Even in the case, all test pass is required, I still want to know if there is a way to add a customized status check to the current pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And where are the 2 status checks mentioned above defined in Jenkins with blue ocean plugin?

This is default behaviour from the plugin.

> How could I do that from Jenkins side?

There's a few options to achieve this but ultimately you'll need to create the new status yourself using the [GitHub Status API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/). This is a simple REST call that creates a new entry on the statuses list with whatever result you pass it on. Now in terms how to do this from Jenkins, I would suggest adding an API call within your Jenkins file and isolate the `unit test` part of the build and pass or fail the result based on the output of that command.

I would take a look at the [Jenkins Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to see if there's some routines that already do the work for you, which in this case you would be looking for a method that encapsulates the API call.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely take a look at your suggestion. Since GitHub Status API looks pretty simple, I will try to create a batch file that update commit status after running unit test (for example).